# JavaScript, HTML: How to tell if option box is has been set?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I am having trouble finding out how to figure out if an HTML dropdown box has been set?

Ok, I understand how I can check the index once it has been activated and an item chosen. But, how do I determine that the box hasn't been touched and no item selected?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you definitely mean "drop down" box?  An item will always be selected for a drop down select element.  The default selected item will be the first option unless another has the `selected` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select.options.selectedIndex will be -1 in that case.

Comment: On a drop-down select box, an item will always be selected.  If no default is set, the selected index will be 0.  In a select box with the size or multiple attributes, when no items are selected the index will be -1, but the OP specifically mentioned drop down.

Comment: @Andy E's head: I understood him to mean "no item selected" ... which is possible, but you're right, not if the box "ahsn't been touched". Self-contradictory statement. In any case, if no item has been selected, the index will be -1. And it can be set to -1 to select nothing.

Comment: it *can* be set to -1, but it's not set to -1 by default.  I knocked up a very quick example for you - http://jsfiddle.net/fYju6/.  The page loads and alerts the selectedIndex, which is 0.  **edit** nm, I misread your last comment as an argument when it was actually an agreement ;-)

Comment: My understanding was that the OP wants to know if an element hasn't been changed

Comment: Perfect.. thanks.

I'm using a multiline select box.

Why didn't I just print the selectedIndex property when there was nothing selected, D'oh..

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't think there's a native method, but you can add an event listener to call a function when the select is changed:

function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
    if (elm.addEventListener) {
        elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
        return true;
    }
    else if (elm.attachEvent) {
        var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
        return r;
    }
    else {
        elm['on' + evType] = fn;
    }
}
hasBeenTouched = false;
addEvent(selectEl, 'change', function() {
    hasBeenTouched = true;
});
```

Comment: it would be wiser to use the focus or blur event, as the change event doesn't fire if you select the currently selected option in the list.

Answer (score 0):

After the document is loaded (naively `window.onload`), manually set the drop-down list `selectedIndex` to `-1` (as others have observed, the default is otherwise for the first item to be selected)

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('ddlId').selectedIndex = -1;
};
```

There's no way for the user to set the drop-down list to unselected through the browser interface, so you can be sure it is both unset and untouched by testing whether the `selectedIndex` is still `-1` at any point after initially setting it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make sure a user has selected an option and not just submitted the form with the default option. This situation is commonly achieved by having a "label" option (sometimes blank to keep the size down) in your drop down box, that is selected by default, followed by validation checking to see if another option has been selected:

```
<select>
  <option>-- Please choose an option -- </option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Using validation properly (both server-side and client-side), you're able to implement a solution **that doesn't rely on Javascript** to check if an option has been properly selected.